# C++ friend operator overloading cin>>

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am replacing a Read in function with a friend operator. I am having trouble referencing the friend operator in a void function. I am receiving and error "No member named 'Read' in Date" in the void GetDates function. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you!

Question 2:
I am now using cout<< operator but I am receiving errors for my variables: "'mn' is a private member of 'Date'"

```
class Date {
private:
    int mn;        //month component of a date
    int dy;        //day component of a date
    int yr;        //year comonent of a date

public:
    //constructors
    Date() : mn(0), dy(0), yr(0)
    {}
    Date(int m, int d, int y) : mn(m), dy(d), yr(y)
    {}

    //input/output functions
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& Read, Date& d);   //overload friend Read
    friend ostream& operator<<(istream& write, Date& d);   //overload friend write                                  
    void GetDates();
    void Sort();
};

//Date class member functions

istream& operator >>(istream& Read, Date& d) //**NEED TO REPLACE with overload vs as friends to Date function**
{
    char skip_char;

    Read >> d.mn >> skip_char >> d.dy >> skip_char >> d.yr;
    return Read;
}


void GetDates(Date l[], int &n)      //reads list l, and returns count in n
   {

       cout << "How many date values are to be processed (1 - 100)? ";
       cin >> n;

       while ((n < 0) || (n > 100)) {
           cout << "Invalid value; enter number between 0 and 100: ";
           cin >> n;
       }

       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           cout << "Enter a date (mm/dd/yyyy): ";
           l[i].Read(); //ERROR HERE
       }
   }



ostream& operator <<(ostream& write, Date& d) //friend write
{
    if (d.mn < 10)
        cout << '0';
    cout << d.mn << '/';
    if (d.dy < 10)
        cout << '0';
    cout << d.dy << '/';
    if (d.yr < 1000)
        cout << '0';
    if (d.yr < 100)
        cout << '0';
    if (d.yr < 10)
        cout << '0';
    cout << d.yr;
    return write;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Read` is the name of the `stream` that you are extracting from. An example of a stream that you can read from is `cin`. You need to replace this line:

```
l[i].Read(); //ERROR HERE
```

with

```
cin >> l[i];
```

Inside `operator>>` the `cin` object is now called `Read`.

The issue with your `operator<<` is that it needs to be declared as a `friend`, the same way you've done with `operator>>`.

Also, you are writing to `cout` instead of writing to `write`. This will not work, as soon as you try to writing to any other stream.

Comment: I am receiving an error for another friend function now. cout - I will add it above

Comment: @larry718 added an answer for that.

Comment: Yes, i did declare as a friend:

friend ostream& operator<<(istream& write, Date& d);   //overload friend read

Comment: No, inside your class, you've declared `operator>>` as a friend, but not `operator<<`.

Comment: I added it above also. Still receiving the error. Thank you SOSO much for your help!

Comment: Ok, you've added it to your question. Now compile it, and check.

Comment: Still getting the error: "mn is a private member of 'Date'"
'dy' is a private member of 'Date'
'yr' is a private member of 'Date'

Comment: You just have a typo in the declaration of `operator<<`. The first argument should be `ostream&`, not `istream&`.

Comment: I had another wrench thrown into my assignment and of course I am getting errors. Can you help out?

Comment: You need to ask a separate question then. And that question needs to stand to be complete on its own. Know that SO is not meant to be useful to individuals only, but for others who might have the same issue. Solving your specific assignment is unlikely to be helpful to others.